# Dúvidas sobre como usar mapas dinâmicos

Tags: google-maps, cep

Minha irmã vende Avon e eu resolvi fazer uma coisa bem simples que são os cadastros dos clientes dela. Até aí tudo bem, mas eu gostaria de adicionar o mapa do Google Maps no site dela. Achei a API da Google mas com um monte de coisas, o que eu quero é coisa simples, ao abrir o cadastro de clientes tem 3 *tabs*
PRINCIPAL | ENDEREÇO | MAPA
Ao clicar na *tab* "mapa" gostaria que dentro da `DIV` ou `IFRAME` ou outro elemento, me mostrasse o mapa do endereço do cliente dela. É coisa simples, algo do tipo assim:

https://www.google.com.br/maps/preview/place/AQUI-VAI-O-CEP

Se eu mudar o CEP e colocar o da minha rua e copiar o link e colar no browser ele abre o link direitinho, agora se eu colocar ele dentro de uma `DIV` ou de um `IFRAME` ele não carrega.

Como resolver?

Comment: Você pegou o código do iframe da própria página do maps? Clique no ícone do elo da corrente e pegue de lá.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tente fazer a URL neste formato:

```
https://www.google.com.br/maps?q=<CEP_COM_TRACO>,%20Brasil&output=embed
```

Um exemplo de como ficaria:

```
https://www.google.com.br/maps?q=49100-000,%20Brasil&output=embed
```

Isso porque o Google Maps Preview (novo Google Maps) que você está usando precisa ser usado por alguém que está logado no Google e aceitou testar essa nova versão!

Espero que ajude!

Comment: Não deu certo Rodolfo. Veja o exemplo:
http://www.zenasloc.com.br/mapa.htm
Continua sem aparecer

Comment: Tente agora, editei a resposta para tentar outra alternativa. não esqueca do `&output=embed` no final da URL

Comment: Certo, com isto eu vou usar a versão antiga do Google né e não terei problemas em saber se o cara está ou não logado. Seria isto? Deu certinho. Confere aí pra você ver:

http://www.zenasloc.com.br/mapa.htm

Funcionou tanto no Chrome quanto no IE.

Comment: Protinho, consegui ajustar até um mapa para pegar uma rota, com isto vou poder saber qual a rota dela de um ponto para outro. Valeu.

Comment: Fico feliz que conseguiu! Exatamente, desta maneira não é necessário que o usuário esteja logado no Google.